# Is it possible to store pointer with two higher-order zero bytes as a WORD when it's not in a cpu register?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, size, cpu-word

On a system where size of a pointer is 4 bytes when the intention is to just address parts of memory that are addressable by two bytes(lower parts), is it possible to store the pointer as a two byte WORD when it's not in some cpu register? I don't see any way cause assuming we've got any WORD like one named "twoBytes" by declaring a pointer like:

```
char * pointer = reinterpret_cast<char *>((unsigned int)(twoBytes))
```

We're introducing a whole new entity with 4 bytes that's gonna be saved as a 4-byte entity.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question but the answer to whether you can drop the two high bytes while saving a pointer is no. Consider a pointer to address 0x8000000; if you drop the high order bytes and later retrieve it the pointer will now point to 0x00000000.

Comment: What is the goal of doing this?  On 32-bit machine four-byte quantity access will be more efficient anyway.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? Reduce memory taken up by pointers?

Comment: @Praetorian_I'm discussing about parts of memory which pointers pointing to them have two zero higher order bytes.

Comment: @Steve M_not every pointer that's meaningless just ones with two higher-order zero bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds more like a compiler feature (good old fashioned "near" pointers) than something you can do from inside the language.  Take it up with whoever made the compiler you're using.  I can vouch for the *theoretical possibility* of being able to implement this behavior in GCC, although I suspect it would be a huge pain in the ass.

As an alternative hack, you might be able to get most of what you want using a base pointer and 'unsigned short' offsets.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can store however little information is needed to recover the original pointer value, so yes, you can, although it's outside the guarantees offered by the language (you need to be sure how your particular compiler treats reinterpret casts).

However, in e.g. Windows the only thing you can be sure of is that the upper word of a 32-bit pointer is *non-zero* for user code (except for nullpointers). This is implicit in the Windows API macros like [MAKEINTATOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649055%28VS.85%29.aspx). If the most significant word could be zero then the APIs couldn't reliably distinguish pointers that represent small integers, from pointers to text strings.

So, in general, optimizing that way won't buy you anything unless you're doing kernel programming. Also, saving a few bytes is seldom worth the added complexity.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: His question would make sense if he were programming a microcontroller or something, where a 16-bit address is realistic.

Comment: Just from his having asked the question *at all* I bet this is an embedded scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, for the same reason you can't store the word "bike" in two bytes.  The data just won't fit.  Don't cast pointers to non-pointer types, it's often non-portable and can silently introduce truncation and cause some nasty bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it without a named 4 byte entity:

```
((char*)(unsigned)twoBytes)[idx] = some_val;
```

`twoBytes` will only take up two bytes in memory. When you cast it to a char*, your compiler will make a 4-byte value to actually address the data, but you'll never see it, and it will likely only ever be in a register. I think that's what you were asking.

Comment: @Chris_That's gonna be a huge pain in the ass by the way since every time dereferencing, this kinda syntax should be used.

Comment: I was answering the question. It bugs me when all the answers say nothing but "you don't want to do that!". People generally have a legitimate reason for their questions ...

Comment: @Chris_glad that bugs you as it does to me also, when the reason behind question is not clear for someone it should not lead to such statements.